# Puma not working with actionmailer preview in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma

I am running `rails 4.2.5.1` and `puma 2.16.0`.  The relevant configurations in my `development.rb` file are

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000, protocol: 'http' }
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { address: 'localhost', port: 1025 }
  config.action_mailer.preview_path = "#{Rails.root}/mailers_previews/"
```

When I go to /rails/mailers then Chrome displays a page 'This webpage is not available'.  If I run webrick instead i.e.

```
rails server webrick
```

then my mailer previews page is displayed.

I have been using puma in development and production on heroku for several months and everything else works.  How do I get puma to display the previews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from [the puma project](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/870#issuecomment-184338466), it turned out that I was using an old url

```
http://0.0.0:3000/rails/mailers
```

when I should have been using

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers
```

The later url works with puma.